# ElasticSearch Fields Mapping to String by default when indexing

Tags: elasticsearch

Let me first explain my scenario. 
I am fetching data from RDBMS and pushing it into ElasticSearch. 
Fetched Results are in the form of List and i am preparing bulk index request like this:

```
BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk(); 
for (Map<String,Object> singleDataRow : ResultSet) 
{ 
       IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("testindex","testtype",singleDataRow.getObject("NAME")); 
       bulkRequest.add(indexRequest); 
} 

bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
```

My Map = includes Map of string to string, string to big decimal, string to big integer etc. 
eg.

```
{ BIRTHDATE : 2015-03-05 , NAME : deepankar , AGE : 22 , AMOUNT : 15.5 }
```

But when i see the mapping of my testtype in testindex, all mapping of fields are of "type" : "string"

Why the fields does not maps to "type": "string" , or "type" : "long" , and even "type" : "date" as elasticsearch does it by default?

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch will attempt to 'guess' the field type by the first insert, unless you create and map fields beforehand.

There are two possible reasons why your fields are being indexed as `string` instead of `long` or any other type:

1. You're not really sending these fields as `int`, so you're sending `'10'` instead of `10`
2. You've already inserted at least 1 document that had a `string` value for that field, so if you've inserted your first document with `AGE: '22'` Elasticsearch will set that field to `type: string` and any future inserts will have a `string` value.

If you want to make sure, you can delete the current index, re-create it and manually set up mapping before inserting the first document, like so:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/testindex/_mapping/testmapping' -d '
{
    "testmapping" : {
        "properties" : {
            "birthdate" : { "type" : "date", "format": "dateOptionalTime" },
            "name" : { "type" : "string" },
            "age" : { "type" : "long" },
            "amount" : { "type" : "double" }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: thankyou for your reply.
Actually i did output the singleDataRow ( MAP<String,Object> ) before calling 
`code` indexRequest(singleDataRow); `code` 
like this :

`code` System.out.println(singleDataRow.get("AGE").getClass()); `code`

Its returning me : 
java.math.BigDecimal

Comment: Is it possible that the first document you inserted into your index was using strings and not integers/floats? In any case, delete the index, create and and use the mapping API to set field types, then insert your documents.

Comment: I dont have any index created. 
I performed `DELETE _all` using sense , and running my java code, 
and when i `GET testindex/_mapping` : all fields have string as their type!

Comment: why mapping is not taking long , float , date automatically? it should make this mapping by default??

Comment: I saw your answer. I know that we can provide mapping using mapping api, but my question is why es is indexing data using `string` as default ?? 
I have my `Map<String,Object> singleDataRow.get("AGE").getClass();` returning as `java.Math.BigDecimal` so its not that my map includes all values as `string`