# Elastic Search is ignoring the mappings and long fields are showing up as strings

Tags: elasticsearch

I am adding a schema to elasticsearch and in the schema I am attempting to add some fields as longs that have previously been processed as strings. I created a new index and reprocessed the data but in the new index those fields are still being shown as strings.

The relevant part of the mappings from the index's endpoint:

```
image_features: {
    properties: {
        brightness: {
            type: "string"
        },
        contrast: {
            type: "string"
        },
        height: {
            type: "long"
        },
        sharpness: {
            type: "string"
        },
        width: {
            type: "long"
        }
    }
}
```

But the return sends back:

```
image_features: {
     width: "400",
     height: "400",
     sharpness: "good",
     contrast: "good",
     brightness: "good"
},
```

I originally created a new index and used reindex to migrate the data. I have also tried creating a new index and reloading all the data through a bulk action. But these values are still remaining strings.

Comment: Hi Jasmine, check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976195/elasticsearch-fields-mapping-to-string-by-default-when-indexing I think it might be helpful to you.

Comment: So I actually have already created an index with defined mappings with these as numbers. But it is letting me send numbers or strings, or both. I'm not clear why as the documentation implies there should be a failure if it is not sending the correct datatype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is the source coming back and ES will always store the source exactly as you send it, and hence, it will return exactly what you send him.

However, you can be sure that the `image_features.height` and `image_features.width` have been handled as long and indexed as such since your mapping declares those fields as `long`.

If you want the source to come back with numeric values you need to send the source with numeric values (see below), ES is not going to transform your source values, which means you need to modify your client process which does the indexing.

```
image_features: {
     width: 400,
     height: 400,
     sharpness: "good",
     contrast: "good",
     brightness: "good"
},
```

Comment: Can you reference any documentation by elasticsearch that explains this behavior?